# Why won't this route with params work in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to get a simple route with a parameter working in Angular2. I'm using Angular **2.0.0-rc.2** and angular router **3.0.0-alpha.7**. Most of what I have is based directly on the updated documentation on routing https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <base href=".">
      ...
```

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app/app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
])
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: 'featured',       component: FeaturedPageComponent },
    { path: 'containers/:id', component: ContainerEditComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**container-edit.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'container-edit',
    templateUrl: 'container-edit.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['container-edit.component.css']
})
export class ContainerEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private sub: any;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            let id = +params['id']; // + converts string to number
            console.log(id);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

When I hit `http://localhost:4200/containers/1337` I get the following error.

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: '1337'

Comment: You do add `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` in `bootstrap()`? Do you use `HashLocationStrategy` or default `PathLocationStrategy`. Does your server support `PathLocationStrategy`?

Comment: Yes, I'll update the question to include it.

Comment: I'm not explicitly specifying a location strategy but based on the documentation I'm assuming `PathLocationStrategy` is the default. I'm using the angular-cli to serve which I believe is configured for paths.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in something like Plunker ? I don't see anything wrong with the code above and I'm using the same version of router with angular cli and it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Set your base to `<base href="/" />` in your index.html. The angular2 documentation pushes you to use `<base href="." />` because throughout their heroes project they specifically use `router.navigate` which is good because it forces you to start from the default route then from there work up a history.

But in some cases where you want the user to be able to directly travel to a particular path then you'd have to use `/`

**Original Answer:**

Check your paths, did you purposely change it? the samples does not include an 'app' subfolder.

```
import { AppComponent } from './app/'; <--- check this
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app/app.routes'; <--- and this
```

Comment: This is how angular-cli set up the project. but those work otherwise I'd be getting import errors. The trailing slash was a typo in my question.

Comment: Oh ok, I used your example along with the plunkr from the documentation and it works fine via this.router.navigate(['/containers', 1337]); -- now if you navigate directly to http://localhost:4200/containers/1337 using the address bar directly the component your loading does not contain your routeconfig hence the 'cannot match' error.

Comment: But my route config is injected in main.ts while bootstrapping. I'm not quite sure I understand.

Comment: Not sure what your folder structure is but try changing your base tag to <base href="/" /> in your index.html. This tells the router the part that shouldn't change. I think your current location isn't pointing to the correct path.

Comment: In the example on the angular site they show `<base href=".">`

Comment: That was it! I changed it to / and it worked. You should create another answer explaining that and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I've also added the fragment of my index.html to show what I had for `<base>`

Comment: On the site they specify the dot because they are using router.navigate which is what they use throughout their heroes samples which is good because it forces you to start from the beginning and work up a history. But in some cases where you want the user to be able to directly travel to a particular path then you'd have to use `/`